# How to hide a component only on home navbar using next.js 13?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, next.js13

I'm finishing my undergraduate degree and creating a website as my course's final project to promote my research. I'm learning next.js just for this.

I have this sidebar in my layout.tsx, but I want to hide the "menuAlt" component only on the homepage. I've done quite a bit of research and haven't found a solution yet. Would anyone know how to help me? Thank you.

```
import Link from "next/link"
import MenuAlt from "../MenuAlt/MenuAlt"



export default function Sidebar() {
    return (
    <div className="flex flex-col justify-between w-40 h-screen py-12 text-sm font-semibold leading-tight text-center text-white align-middle bg-black border-black">
        <MenuAlt/>
        <Link
            className="hover:scale-110"
            href="/">
            JOGO DA MOBILIDADE ATIVA
            </Link>
    </div>
    )
}
```

I've tride to useRouter, but it can't seem to work, don't know what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 'use client'
 
import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation'
import Link from "next/link"
import MenuAlt from "../MenuAlt/MenuAlt"

export default function Sidebar() {
    const pathname = usePathname();
    return (
    <div className="flex flex-col justify-between w-40 h-screen py-12 text-sm font-semibold leading-tight text-center text-white align-middle bg-black border-black">
        {pathname !== 'homepage-path' && <MenuAlt/>}
        <Link
            className="hover:scale-110"
            href="/">
            JOGO DA MOBILIDADE ATIVA
            </Link>
    </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to hide some paths you can use this method

```js
import Link from "next/link"
import MenuAlt from "../MenuAlt/MenuAlt"
import { useRouter } from "next/router"

export default function Sidebar() {
    const { pathname } = useRouter()
    const disablePathname = ["/first-pathname", "/second-pathname"]

    return (
    <div className="flex flex-col justify-between w-40 h-screen py-12 text-sm font-semibold leading-tight text-center text-white align-middle bg-black border-black">
        {!disablePathname.includes(pathname) ? <MenuAlt/> : null}
        <Link
            className="hover:scale-110"
            href="/">
            JOGO DA MOBILIDADE ATIVA
            </Link>
    </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).